# Protractor Typescript to launch application using baseUrl

Tags: angular, typescript, gruntjs, protractor

I am using Protractor typescript for automation of angular application. When i run the using "npm run e2e" then i have observed that angular is always listening on https://localhost:4200.

I Tried to declare baseUrl in Protractor.conf.js as param as below -

```
params:
    {
    baseUrl: 'http://www.angular.io'}
    ,
```

I am passing that baseUrl to navigate method in e2e-spec.ts as below -

```
 page.navigateTo(browser.params.baseUrl);
```

But i don't want to pass Url each time in it block to the navigate() method. So i want baseUrl should be set once and reflected or used by all spec-ts file as base url. Like when i run the application using "npm run e2e" it automatically launches https://localhost:4200

Can you please help me , how to change url at one place e.g. in protraactor.conf.js and it should automatically used by navigate() in spec.ts.

Thanks for you help...

Comment: Have you tried adding `baseUrl: 'http://www.angular.io'` in protractor.conf.js as a top level property? (e.g. on the same level as `specs`, `capabilities`, `onPrepare` etc.)

Comment: Basically i want to know how it always launch localhost:4200. I read it is due to default behavior i.e. angular always listening on 4200.

Comment: Yes i have tried  but it still launching localhost:4200, When i call -page.navigateTo('/'); then expectation is it should navigate to baseUrl which i have provided

Comment: this command worked for me protractor --basurl=http://www.sites.net but dont why it is not working when i set base url and say npm run e2e

Comment: Please show your `package.jsonn` in your question

Answer (score 1):

Declare the baseUrl in config file as below,

```
exports.config = {
framework: 'custom',
//frameworkPath: protractorCucumberFramework,
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),

seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
baseUrl: 'your application url',

//Browser Configurations
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
        // Chrome is controlled by automated software : disable"
        'args': ['disable-infobars=true'],
    }
},
```

And in Spec file, Call the baseUrl as mentioned below,

```
 browser.get("");
```

It Should work.